# How to schedule WSUS Offline media update?

Tags: wsus-offline

I'm an ardent user of [**WSUS Offline**](http://www.wsusoffline.net/).

What I'm trying to figure out is:

- How to schedule WSUS Offline's media update to happen automatically (i.e., with Scheduled Task)

After some searching, the only information I found is a short Answer in [WSUS Offline's FAQ](https://svn.wsusoffline.net/svn/wsusoffline/trunk/doc/faq-enu.txt), namely:

> Q: Is it possible to automate the creation of the update media (CD/DVD images), with a scheduled task maybe? If yes, how do I do that?
>
> A: Create a new batch file in the ".\cmd" directory, e. g. "DownloadUpdatesAndCreateISOImage.cmd". Then enter the desired calls to "DownloadUpdates.cmd" and "CreateISOImage.cmd" with the required options into this file. An example of such a file would be:
>
> ```
> @echo off
> call DownloadUpdates wxp enu
> call CreateISOImage wxp enu
> ```
>
> Next, create a scheduled task for your new custom script "DownloadUpdatesAndCreateISOImage.cmd" and select the desired run time. For example, if you intend to create new update media following each Microsoft Patchday, select "second Wednesday of every month".

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any other documentation on this procedure.

So, my questions:

- Have anyone tried the above method successfully?
- Are there "gotcha's" that I must be aware of?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main gotcha is that it does not run from a UNC path. So if you're running it from a different system than the files reside you will have to make some changes.

You can actually create the batch file from the application by checking the "Only create collection script" checkbox.

For running off a share I copy the batch file created above to a local folder and add these lines to the top and run it from a scheduled task.

```
net use w: \\nas\tools /persistent:no /user:nas\tools password
w:
cd wsusoffline\cmd\custom
```